# Is there a way to get query being fired in eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a requirement where I need to grab the Insert and Update Native SQL statement being fired and store it in a log table in the DB. Is it possible for me to get the query in eclipselink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your own custom logger that logs to your database rather than to the file system and configure eclipselink.logging.level.sql=FINE in the persistence unit. Then you can piggy-back on the existing solution for logging SQL statements and save them to the log table. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomLogger and https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging for details.

Comment: Is it possible to find out which Entity Class is being used while creating a custom logger and I only need it for Insert/Update, not for Select

Comment: I don't think you can do that without parsing the message. Checking for insert/update should be easy, just check for those keywords. Getting the entity is a bit more complex, but you can parse out the table and map it to the class? You could use an EntityListener instead, but that will not give you the native SQL.